# cannot resolve symbol[string] when using updateByQuery with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-painless, update-by-query

I have the following set-up:

mapping:

```
esClient.indices.putMapping({
  index: 'tests',
  body: {
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: 'text',
      },
      lastName: {
        type: 'text',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

this is the result when I post an entry:

[image]

this is the result when I query the entries:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/tests/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'       
{
"size": 1000,
"query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}
'
{
  "took" : 18,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "tests",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "KJbtj3kBRlqnip7VJLLI",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "lastName" : 1,
          "name" : "lucas"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**I tried to update the entry's last name with the following curl:**

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/tests/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.lastName='johnson'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "lucas"
    }
  }
}
'
```

AND THIS IS THE ERROR I'M GETTIN:

```
    {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "ctx._source.lastName=johnson",
          "                     ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "ctx._source.lastName=johnson",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 21,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 28
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "ctx._source.lastName=johnson",
      "                     ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "ctx._source.lastName=johnson",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "position" : {
      "offset" : 21,
      "start" : 0,
      "end" : 28
    },
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "cannot resolve symbol [johnson]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

If I put an integer instead of a string it updates it otherwise I keep getting that error.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to surround the new `lastName` field value with `' '`**.

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"lucas",
    "lastName":"erla"
}
```

**Query:**

```
POST _update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.lastName='johnson'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "lucas"
    }
  }
}
```

**After hitting the update by query API, the document will be updated to**

```
GET /_doc/1

{
  "_index": "67641538",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 3,
  "_seq_no": 2,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "lastName": "johnson",
    "name": "lucas"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lucas Erlacher please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hi @ESCoder. Thanks a lot for taking your time and the reply. I tried to follow your suggestion but still getting the same error. This is strange.

Comment: @LucasErlacher that's weird :\ May I know which version of elasticsearch are you using? I tested the above query in ES version 7.12, and its working fine

Comment: @LucasErlacher And the error which you pointed out in the question, is not the updated error which you are getting. Correct ?

Comment: Hi @ESCoder. I tried your solution with Node and on ES's console and it works. Strange that it doesn't with Mac's Terminal. Thanks a lot again. Wanted to upvote your answer but I'm still 15 reputation short to cast a vote. Have a nice week.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to surround the new lastName field value with `" "`.**

I faced similar problem and I solved by adding `" "` instead of `' '`. My ES version is 8.4.

**QUERY**.

```
 

    curl -X POST "localhost:9200/tests/_update_by_query?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
      "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.lastName=\"johnson\"",
        "lang": "painless"
      },
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "name": "lucas"
        }
      }
    }
    '
```